# WordPress with React: Saving and Using Data Collected with fetch

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I am trying to do a basic thing with react, which is access an endpoint created by my locally installed WordPress website so that I can use that data and render it in a way I like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Widget extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var data = fetch("http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);


        // this.state = {
        //   value: 'foo2',
        //   posts: data.value,
        // };

      })


    this.state = {
      value: 'foo2',
      posts: data.value,
    };

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>value: {this.state.posts}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Widget.propTypes = {
  wpObject: PropTypes.object
};
```

I am trying to set the state to the data but it is returned as a promise.  Apparently I can `console.log` the data but I cannot use it in the `render` function.  You can see that I try to set the state in the second `.then()` but when I uncomment that and delete the thing below it everything stops working.  If I cannot set the state inside the `.then()` how do I use the returned data in the `render()` function?

Comment: This is really more of a React/JavaScript question. The fact that the URL is a WordPress endpoint isn't really relevant. As such it would be more appropriate at https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: oh, my mistake... that is exactly why I thought the question belonged here